# Any additional points/badges for hits from search engines?

Tags: feature-request, badges, search

I suppose that questions, that attract many unique users from external search engines can be valued by additional points/badges. For example there may be a badge for the question that attracted more hits from search engines then other questions during one day.

Comment: At what point do we just rename the site BadgeOverflow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ick, no.

That's just begging to gamed. We don't want people playing "SEO for questions" with weird irrelevant keywords etc on StackOverflow, IMO.

Comment: Agreed. We don't need this.