# Indexed badge

Tags: discussion, badges

**Indexed** (silver) & **Highly Indexed** (gold) - Question has X page views from referal sites; google, yahoo and the like.

The idea is that questions that are more relevant to the "outside" world (IE search engines, blog posts, etc.) would be encouraged and rewarded.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5657

Answer (score 1):

I think this could potentially lead to some pretty serious abuse which Google may not like.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of discussion, let's ignore the potential for garnering this badge by link-farming your own questions... What behavior *on SO* does this encourage, specifically?

Comment: To me it would reward better thought out questions, since a question about a problem many people have, but that doesn't have a decent enough answer on the net would float up to the top of the inter-webs -- It may encourage really stupid questions too... like questions about boats.  But those tend to get culled quickly